# Planning to buy laptop, want to install Ubuntu on it, any limitations?

Tags: installation, laptop

I'm planning to buy a laptop and want to install Ubuntu on it, 
are there certain hardware types which Ubuntu doesn't work on?

I'm really no hardware expert, I assume I won't buy anything from Apple though because it's made for OS X I believe.
I got some recommendations on Dell so far but really not decided yet

Comment: Try to avoid nvidia optimus enabled laptop.

Comment: @Web-E thank you, how do I know if a laptop comes with Optimus, does that depend on the graphics card only, I mean do I only need to check if the graphics card features Optimus?

Comment: Check for hardware spec in the site. Nvidia now a days pack almost all card with optimus.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are considered off topic on Ask Ubuntu, check the FAQ. This will just end up in "My laptop is better than your laptop!"

Answer (score 4):

Buy a laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed on it, so everything will work out of the box and you don't have to spend money on a windows license that you will not use, but most important, this way you are voting with your wallet for Linux supporting hardware.

[System76](https://www.system76.com) is a company that that build laptops, desktops and servers with Ubuntu on it.

[Here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/212014/how_to_buy_ubuntu_preloaded.html) is an article that mentions several companies that ship Ubuntu-preloaded-computers.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe there are is that much hardware limitations for Ubuntu, as it can be installed on older computers as well.

The best place to find the specs Ubuntu needs, is the official Specifications Page, which can be found here: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 2):

Look for an [Ubuntu Certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) laptop via Google.  A quick Google of model/make + Ubuntu usually does the trick. (Or check the whole list under above link.)  Lenovo & Dell are pretty good.  A little research into what the developers of your preferred distro use never goes amiss...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid laptops with hybrid graphics, they are nothing but trouble. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The state of drivers for Broadcom wifi adapters is not entirely stable, so I would avoid them if you can. Centrino-based systems are usually considered better, due to all the work that Intel has put into their wireless drivers.